How come my code can't draw ellipses according to JSON coordinate?
I'm trying a basic map drawing with JSON file.
What I'm trying to do is simply draw ellipse according the latitude and longitude in the JSON file. I'm creating a for loop to define the variable of [] arry, but when I print xgeo and ygeo, the error message shows "r is undefined". And none of ellipse is drawn.
let bkgImage;
let urlMap, urlC;
let mapGeoLeft, mapGeoRight, mapGeoBottom, mapGeoTop;
let xgeo, ygeo;
let w, h;



function preload() {
  urlMap =
    "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v11/static/[-123,29.7604267,-70.2553259,41]/600x400@2x?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN";
  urlC = loadJSON("cities.json") 
  
  bkgImage = loadImage("US.Map.png");
}


function setup() {
  let u1 = split(urlMap,"/"); //string
  let u2 = u1[8]; //taking coordinate info.
  let coord = split(u2,","); // taking off ,
  coord[0] = coord[0].replace("[",""); //taking off []
  coord[3] = coord[3].replace("]","");
  
  mapGeoLeft = coord[0];
  mapGeoRight = coord[2];
  mapGeoTop = coord[1];
  mapGeoBottom = coord[3];

  createCanvas(600, 400);
  image(bkgImage, 0, 0, width, height);
  
  print(mapGeoRight);
  print(mapGeoLeft)
}

function draw() {
  for(let r = 0; r < urlC.length; r++){
    let lon = urlC[r].longitude
    let lat = urlC[r].latitude
    
    let xgeo = map(lon, mapGeoLeft, mapGeoRight, 0, width);
    let ygeo = map(lat, mapGeoTop, mapGeoBottom, 0, height);
    
    fill(255,0,0);
    ellipse(xgeo, ygeo, 5, 5)
    
  }

  // print(lon);
  
  noLoop();
}



Part of the JSON file I'm using:
[
  {
    "city": "New York",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "4.8%",
    "latitude": 40.7127837,
    "longitude": -74.0059413,
    "population": "8405837",
    "rank": "1",
    "state": "New York"
  },
  {
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "4.8%",
    "latitude": 34.0522342,
    "longitude": -118.2436849,
    "population": "3884307",
    "rank": "2",
    "state": "California"
  },
  {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "-6.1%",
    "latitude": 41.8781136,
    "longitude": -87.6297982,
    "population": "2718782",
    "rank": "3",
    "state": "Illinois"
  },
  {
    "city": "Houston",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "11.0%",
    "latitude": 29.7604267,
    "longitude": -95.3698028,
    "population": "2195914",
    "rank": "4",
    "state": "Texas"
  },
  {
    "city": "Philadelphia",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "2.6%",
    "latitude": 39.9525839,
    "longitude": -75.1652215,
    "population": "1553165",
    "rank": "5",
    "state": "Pennsylvania"
  },
  {
    "city": "Phoenix",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "14.0%",
    "latitude": 33.4483771,
    "longitude": -112.0740373,
    "population": "1513367",
    "rank": "6",
    "state": "Arizona"
  },
  {
    "city": "San Antonio",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "21.0%",
    "latitude": 29.4241219,
    "longitude": -98.4936282,
    "population": "1409019",
    "rank": "7",
    "state": "Texas"
  },
  {
    "city": "San Diego",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "10.5%",
    "latitude": 32.715738,
    "longitude": -117.1610838,
    "population": "1355896",
    "rank": "8",
    "state": "California"
  },
  {
    "city": "Dallas",
    "growth_from_2000_to_2013": "5.6%",
    "latitude": 32.7766642,
    "longitude": -96.7969879,
    "population": "1257676",
    "rank": "9",
    "state": "Texas"


Which line is getting that error?

Since we don't have your tokens, can you remove any code that's not relevant, or mock the response so we have a [mcve]? Thanks. The error you mention doesn't seem obviously related to the code you shared, since r is very much defined and used normally within the scope of its definition.

when I try to print(lon/lat/xgeo/ygeo) after the for loop. Because no ellipse is showing, I'm thinking the the value of [r] is not been taken correctly.

The only uses of r I can see are urlC[r] and r is clearly assigned in the for loop header. So it's can't be happening there. You must be using r outside that scope.

Variables declared with let are block-scoped. So you can't reference any of them outside the for loop.

Put the console.log() call inside the loop.

Put console.log(urlC.length) before the loop. I'll bet that will explain why there are no ellipses.

@ggorlen I think it's just for loop?

@Barmar the for loop is where r only used. the console.log not making ellipse as well...... Am I taking the longitude and latitude information correctly?

If urlC is the array coming from that JSON, urlC[r].longitude is the correct way to get the longitude. But it can't possibly say that r is undefined. Are you sure you're even going into the loop? If urlC.length is 0 or undefined, the loop stops immediately.

@Barmar urlC is just a random name I gave to the variable, it has to be an existing term from JSON??

Of course not. You can use any name for your variables. I just mean that your code for getting the latitude and longitude is correct if the JSON you showed is actually what's being loaded into that variable.

Have you done console.log(urlC.length) yet? I've made reference to that several times already.

@Barmar where to put it? Is it: for(let r = 0; r < console.log(urlC.length); r++)

Put it right before the loop. Don't you understand the point of it?

@Barmar to be honest I don't know what console.log is.....

It's how you print things to the browser's console in JavaScript. Earlier you said you tried to print all these variables. What did you use if you didn't use console.log(longitude)?
